# Правильно ли оформляются названия некоторых кинофильмов?

Tags: пунктуация

Раз уж на сайте недавно задавали вопрос про названия зарубежных кинофильмов, хотелось бы спросить о нюансе, на который я, например, ответить не могу. Четыре раза интересовался на gramota.ru - feedback отсутствует. ))

Вопрос следующий: почему наши "локализаторы" пишут, к примеру, "Властелин колец: Братство кольца" или "Терминатор: Генезис", а потом и в РФ создают фильм "Бригада 2: Наследник"? А почему, собственно, слово после двоеточия начинается с заглавной? На основании чего? Понимаю, что это опять же "калька" с англоязычного названия, но у нас-то правила отличаются... Спасибо.

Comment: В чём вопрос? Понятно, что вам "Справка" не ответила. Если только про заглавную, то потому, что имя собственное, название.

Comment: А то, что до двоеточия, - не название, нет? Вступление? ))

Comment: Проблема в том, что в русском языке такие написания не регламентированы правилами пунктуации. Здесь надо исходить из того, что вторая часть имя собственное, поэтому прописную букву можно считать оправданной.

Comment: Кстати, на форуме "Вопрос филологом'' также обсуждался такой вопрос. Многие, кстати, согласились, что нужна прописная буква. К сожалению, ссылку не могу представить - не помещается здесь.

Comment: Серж простите, но устанавливать защиту на вопрос который вызывает вполне законные претензии по качеству я считаю некорректным.

Comment: *"Вопрос филологом''* - кем вопрос? )))) Да еще ссылка не помещается.

Comment: behemothus, а в  чем проблема? Обыкновенный вопрос. Защитил, потому что увидел, что кто-то голосовал за закрытие вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

В этом случае мы имеем   название, **состоящее из двух самостоятельных частей, поэтому каждая часть пишется с прописной буквы.**

Примером написания двойных названий является сложные названия литературных произведений с пояснительным союзом  ИЛИ; в нашем случае функцию союза выполняет двоеточие.

**Правило:** Если имя собственное состоит из двух названий, соединяемых союзом ИЛИ, то первое слово второго названия также пишется с прописной буквы: «Дон Жуан, или Каменный гость».

Comment: Это общеизвестно - про две части названия с "или". Можно вспомнить и "Добро пожаловать...", и "Иронию судьбы...". Там-то все понятно. Тогда зачем нужно двоеточие? Какую смысловую нагрузку оно несет в подобных названиях фильмов?

Comment: Как обычно, раскрывает содержание  и взаимосвязь двух частей.  Та же самая функция выполняется   заголовках с двоеточием: называется общая тема и затем следует ее уточнение. Но там используется строчная буква, а здесь прописная во втором названии.

Comment: Вот! Вы сами только что заметили отсутствие логики... Там и здесь. Почему? И еще. Если мы имеем как бы два не связанных между собой варианта названия (типа автор не смог выбрать, какое ему нравится чуть более), то получаем: "Ирония судьбы, или С легким паром!" Можно использовать хоть первую часть (самостоятельно), хоть вторую, какая больше нравится... Так? А что во втором случае? Вроде как уточнение, чтобы не спутали с фильмом-предшественником. Но мы же не пишем, условно говоря: "Место встречи изменить нельзя: Серия № 2"?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно писать с точкой : «Властелин колец. Братство кольца.» В русском языке после двоеточия пишется строчная буква. Понятно,что мы говорим о названиях трилогии и отдельной части. Однако, когда пишут через двоеточие –это явная калька с английского. Другой случай – «Ирония судьбы, или С легким паром», где авторами дается альтернативный заголовок,который отделяется запятой. Грамота.ру разрешает писать и двоеточие, но тогда заголовок части идет со строчной буквы:«Матрица: перезагрузка».Но мне кажется, что смысл при этом теряется.

Comment: Абсолютно с вами согласен. )) С каждым словом. Сам всегда считал, что правильно писать именно с точкой. Но... в спорах оставался в меньшинстве. Теперь буду знать хотя бы, что не я один так считаю... ))

Comment: Так считают специалисты грамота.ру. Кому еще верить? Там много об этом написано, Вы плохо искали.

Comment: Просто лично мне они так и не сподобились ответить. Видимо, заняты были, отвечая десять раз в день, как правильно: "карова" или "корова"... А самому не удалось найти нигде в ответах. Если они такого мнения (это я про написание с точкой), теперь можно спать по ночам спокойно... ))

Comment: @V.V.  - *Так считают специалисты грамота.ру.*  - считают-то они правильно в данном случае, но вот верить им - упаси Боже. Там из "специалиствов" остался, кажется, один Володя Пахомов, который последнее время озабочен всё больше тем, чтобы изгнать с тамошнего форума инакомыслящих. Отвечают (и раньше отвечали) случайные люди.

Comment: Ваша поддержка вдохновляет, спасибо.

Comment: To behemothus  Идите-таки в чат, членоголовый вы наш. )) Вы живете в страшном апокалиптическом мире, где все забрызгано блевотиной и черной краской. "Все враги, везде заговор, я один на страже того немногого, что еще осталось чистым!" ))