# Знаки препинания в двойных названия

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.
Какой знак препинания стоит поставить в названии фильма?

Пример:

Терминатор 2 () судный день.

По какому принципу ставятся знаки в подобных названиях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**«Термина́тор 2: Су́дный день»** (англ. Terminator 2: Judgment Day; США, 1991 год)

Другой пример: **"Властелин колец: Братство кольца»**.

**А какие могут быть варианты,** если второе название раскрывает содержание первого, имеющего более общий смысл?

Если написать через точку, то эта **связь не будет отражена**. Если написать двоеточие и строчную букву, то это не годится для второго названия, которое претендует на **самостоятельность,** а не является частью общего названия.

Вопрос уже обсуждался.

[Правильно ли оформляются названия некоторых кинофильмов?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422327/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2)