# Нужна ли запятая в заголовке?

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

Если сложносочиненное предложение состоит из вопросительного и номинативного (назывного) предложений, нужна ли между ними запятая? Например:

КАК ПОСТУПИМ ДАЛЬШЕ ИЛИ СЛОЖНОСТИ В ПРИНЯТИИ РЕШЕНИЙ

Comment: Вопрос обсуждался: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427098/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как поступим дальше, или сложности в принятии решений**

С точки зрения грамматики, это ССП с союзом ИЛИ, перед которым ставится запятая. У Розенталя рассматриваются разные виды заголовков, но здесь,  как мне кажется,  тот случай, который он относит к общим основаниям.

[РАЗДЕЛ 16. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В ГАЗЕТНЫХ И ЖУРНАЛЬНЫХ ЗАГОЛОВКАХ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=168#pp168)

8. Запятая в заголовках ставится на общих основаниях (т. е. в случаях, предусмотренных правилами ее постановки).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ дан @Sergey ([Правильно ли оформляются названия некоторых кинофильмов?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422327/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2)):

В этом случае мы имеем название, состоящее из двух самостоятельных частей, поэтому каждая часть пишется с прописной буквы.

Примером написания двойных названий являются сложные названия литературных произведений с пояснительным союзом ИЛИ.

Правило: Если имя собственное состоит из двух названий, соединяемых союзом ИЛИ, то первое слово второго названия также пишется с прописной буквы: «Дон Жуан, или Каменный гость».

Comment: _Alenka: 
Но здесь нет никаких названий..._ ===  Как это нет? А что есть? Заголовок? Так, по-моему, _заголовок = заглавие = название (статьи, раздела...)_