# Заголовок из двух предложений. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, цитата, заголовок

Такой случай — в заголовке статьи два предложения. Первое представляет собой закавыченную цитату с вопросительным знаком в конце.

Вопрос: нужна ли точка после первого предложения?

**«Вы уху ели?». Не общайся близко со спортсменами, лишишься права критики**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужна ли запятая в заголовке?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433882/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 5):

*«Вы уху ели?» Не общайся близко со спортсменами, лишишься права критики*

Точка - знак конца повествовательного предложения, а где у нас повествовательное предложение? Его нет. Есть только прямая речь, оканчивающаяся вопросительным знаком. Не вижу условий постановки точки.

Вот вместо запятой я бы поставила двоеточие, ведь во втором предложении причина:

*Не общайся близко со спортсменами (почему?): лишишься права критики*

Может быть и тире, сейчас часто двоеточие заменяют тире для обозначения причинно-следственных связей, тем более, что есть оттенок следствия:

*«Вы уху ели?»  Не общайся близко со спортсменами -  лишишься права критики*

Comment: Первая точка в конце заголовка - описка?

Comment: Конечно, не углядела. С глазами беда...

Comment: Я исправил (убрал точку)

Comment: Спасибо. С Вами приятно иметь дело.

Comment: Людмила, Вы, главное, делитесь своим несметным багажом, а точки я за Вас готов расставлять/убирать и дальше :)) А еще подсказка на всякий случай: если нажать Ctrl и крутить колесико мышки, то можно увеличить избражение практически до любых размеров

Comment: Вот спасибо! А то я уже собралась попрощаться с сайтом - ангиопатия замучила, у меня вообще с сосудами беда, а тут ещё катаракта растёт, вижу всё хуже. И так редко захожу,  некоторые возмущаются неряшливостью печати, а я рада, что вообще могу ещё печатать, жаль совсем уходить.

Answer (score 1):

Специально этот случай, насколько знаю, в нормативных источниках не оговаривается. Но поскольку знаки в заголовках проставляются по тем же правилам, что и в обычном тексте (кроме последней точки), то вопрос сводится к тому, нужна ли вообще такая точка - **в любом тексте**.

Вопрос спорный. 
Вот примеры таких дискуссий:
http://yermolovich.ru/board/1-1-0-88
https://gramotno.livejournal.com/24162.html
https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/4538257.html

Тут важно не то, к каким выводам авторы пришли, а то, какими аргументами обе стороны оперируют. Если в двух словах, то очень сомнительными. Бесспорных аргументов нет ни у одной стороны.

Поэтому позволю себе дать рекомендацию: точку в заголовке (и вообще в любом подобном тексте) сохранять  из чисто практических соображений.
Я тоже сталкивался с эти вопросом и могу сказать, что среди сторонников точки гораздо больше упертых личностей, которые не простят вам её отсутствие. А нерекомендующие эту точку ставить куда боле либеральны.

Разумеется, если будет найдет авторитетный источник с иными рекомендациями, моё предложение можете считать никчемным.

Comment: В приведённых примерах рассматривается цитата в конце вводящего её предложения. Там может возникнуть вопрос о сохранении точки от основного, повествовательного предложения. А здесь каково происхождение точки, если приведена законченная цитата?

Comment: @Alex_ander Так в том-то и дело, что нет внятного общепризнанного правила, что точка в конце цитаты не нужна.